# I can't see textures in Game Engine

Tags: texturing, uv, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, image

I unwrapped the plane and cube using UV unwrap. I added an Image. My view is set to texture. But when I press P the textures are not shown. I cant figure out the problem.

I made the project using this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBVoKL3sbnw

This is my project file - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzymlv8wN9TiZ2Mwb2lDRWJCSHM

I saw many similar questions on this forum but cant figure out the problem. I am a beginner and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you created materials using textures?

Comment: I told you I am a beginner. No idea of technical terms!! Let me tell you the steps I did. First I unwrapped(UV unwrap) the plane -> Then I opened UV image editor -> Then I clicked on open image and selected an image. That's it. But when I press P the texture doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a material for your object—go to the Materials tab (looks like a ball) in the panel on the right and hit the plus button. Then to to the Textures tab, one to the right. You should be able to add your image there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked when I set the coordinates to UV

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.